# Is it against the rules if you let your friends kill you online?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Is it against the rules if you use a tactical insertion to let your friends kill you online in Black Ops 2 to help them unlock camos?

Answer (score 2):

Illegal, no. But it raises certain moral questions, as you're essentially letting the other team win, by forfeiting your life.

Whether or not anyone would see a pattern and then report you for your actions, is another question entirely. I guess you could get banned, if enough people see and report you.

Comment: thanks for answering so fast...you are right about letting my teamates down and lose the game but if i do this for 3 matches only...i could get banned or reported?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many matches you do it for, you could do it for years and never get noticed, or you could do it twice and get banned / reported.